# TFS Build Replication Project Web Base in others projects

Tags: c#, web, tfs, msbuild, projects

How do I mount a build that has a basic web design and replicates to other projects?
I do not want replicate the basic things manually that are in common use in other projects, such as the menu, layout pattern, etc ...

I'm a few days researching solutions to this problem, but find little reference.!

[Image Sample!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqr6E.png)

Comment: It will have nothing to do with a TFS build. You need a way to start each project with a common set of files. That's not a build.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I'm making use of google translator.

I've worked on projects that the procedure was performed at the time of build the master project, so I used that description in question. But I am open to other solutions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a Nuget package with content references

Have a look here: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference scroll down to the content file section for details on how to do that.  This way you can keep a packaged version of your common files, if you upgrade them then you only need to upgrade the Nuget package in your solution and presto.

Comment: Hi Etienne,

I did not want to depend on third-party service nor internet to make this reference. Is there any way to reference local content?

I thank your help

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Etienne I managed to create a NuGetFeed site local and found this reference http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore-with-team-build but still do not know create packages with my base project.

I'll keep searching if they let me know news

Comment: You just need to create a nuspec file and then use the command line "nuget pack blah.nuspec" and then "nuget push blah.nupkg feed" in the post build script (if you are on 2013) if not then you may need need to update you build template.  If you are on TFS 2010 look at Nuggeter on codeplex.